# Jquery: How to not allow next $.post(), till previous is resolved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a chat page where multiple $.post() are performed at once. The server throws **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** when multiple $.post() are performed at once.
To minimize, I have created a [test page](http://whomshop.com/a.php). An ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE occurs when input is given continuously for some seconds. 
The page contents:

**a.php**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) { $(".abc").keyup(function(){
     var a = $(this).val();
     $(".showoff").text("wait..");
     $.post('bbs.php',{a:a},function(abc){
     $(".showoff").html(abc);
     }); });}); 
</script> 
<input type="textbox" class="abc"> <div class="showoff">Type to Change Me!</div>
```

**bbs.php**

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['a'];
?>
```

I think this problem might be because multiple request are made before the previous one is responded. 
So, how to not allow next post, till previous is resolved? Or, What could be the problem behind this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you help me with a sentinel flag?

Comment: This almost looks like an auto-complete situation. Is that the aim? A timer with reset is the usual solution if that is the case. Each time you press a key it cancels any previous timer and starts a new timer. When timer ends stop the timer and send the request, then start timer again.

Comment: Refresh this page more often... have removed my previous comments as irrelevant. Please check new comment :)

Comment: Kind of.  How to set the timer?

Comment: with `setTimeout`? :) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: putting an example together

Comment: Ok. I'll Check that.

Comment: Added answer to your other, duplicate, question :) Best to not repeat a question on SO, but instead try to improve the original.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending http requests to your server every time a key is pressed, maybe your server cannot respond to all these requests at same time.

So, you could add an `if` statement checking if the key pressed is an enter, and after the press of enter disable the input and enable again after the response of the ajax request?

Comment: If this turns out to be an auto-complete scenario, which it appears to be, this is not an appropriate solution. Code would be nice too, else this should have been a comment